# US: carrying forward home office deduction

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, self-employment, home-office

Business expenses in excess of business income can't be deducted the same year but can be "carried forward" and deducted in future years. However, based on a plain reading of rules regarding the home office deduction, it *seems* that the home office deduction is hard-capped at income minus other expenses that year. Can home office expenses in excess of that cap be carried forward and deducted in future years?

Comment: Where are these rules that you're plain reading? Can you quote what it is you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Under the *regular method* for computing the deduction, you may be able
> to carry forward some of these business expenses to the next year,
> subject to the gross income limitation for that year. There's no
> carryover provision under the *safe harbor method*, but you may elect
> into and out of the safe harbor method in any given year.

[emphasis added]. Looks like you should use the regular method if interested in carrying forward to future years.

https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc509